# Scale down large image and keep the quality

Tags: gimp

I have one huge logo with dimensions 1770x1770 and need to scale it down to 80x80. The logo is not complicated and shouldn't loose quality but when I scale it down, it looks really bad, quality is drastically decreased and text is not readable at all.

I know that beginning dimensions look huge but the logo is simple so it should be possible to keep good quality.

The best results which I had were when I was scaling the image in a couple of phases by 20-30%.

Thoughts? Thank you :)

Comment: You can change the interpolation mode. Btw, this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Xufox, thanks but I've tried that and no luck. I know it's not related to programming but I've found many questions about graphic on stackoveflow and they were allowed. Software related questions can be posted and gimp is often used tag :)

Comment: With simple image there is **no way** to change its size without losing quality. You can try different interpolation techniques and choose the best result in your opinion. For changing size of an image without losing quality you have to have it saved as **vector graphic** for example

Comment: @Amadeusz, thank you. I also have it in `.eps` format but can't open it in gimp.

Comment: You can try to install Ghostscript which is a plugin that enables reading and writting PostScript (*.eps) files in Gimp: http://docs.gimp.org/da/gimp-using-external-programs.html

Comment: You could also try InkScape or some other SVG editor.

Comment: This question would really belong in http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/  (the close as off-topic wizard options does not offer a way to migrate it there)

Comment: @Xufox, I can't open eps with IncScape.

Answer (score 0):

It is of the nature of raster images they cannot change size with impunity.

If you have your logo in a vector format, like SVG, or postscript, you better use another program to generate a low resolution version of it.

Otherwise, if the original is raster, them one way to try to reduce it is to downscale it a bit of a time (around 10%), and run enhance-filters at each step. It will yield you a better result, but still far from perfect.

You can do that programatically - open up a Python console in `filters->python->console`

Then, retrieve a reference to your image with:
`img = gimp.image_list()[0]` (the `0` ) referes to the last image tab open - use "1" for the one before that, and so on.

And them just type:

```
while img.width > 80:
    pdb.gimp_image_scale(img, int(img.width * 0.9), int(img.height * 0.9))
    pdb.plug_in_unsharp_mask(img, img.layers[0], 3, 0.5, 4)
```

(If you know nothing about Python: beware of the identation - the two lines inside the `while` must have a common whitespace prefix - and hit  in a blank line to actually execute it)